# Not calling function during deserialization

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there a way to not call a function during class deserialization like:

```
private int _number
public int Number
{
    get
    {
        return _number;
    }
    set
    {
        _number = value
        //do not call this function during deserialization
        CallAnotherFunction()
    }
}
```

When MongoDB deserializes the object and set the `Number` property, it is calling `CallAnotherFunction()` because it is in the set. Is there a flag or anything that can be used to that `CallAnotherFunction()` doesn't get called during deserialization? Currently it is calling the function and adding duplicate values every time during deserialization.

Comment: I don't the answer to your question, but it suggests your design in wrong - you should not really have side effects in your setters, other than assigning the variable, otherwise you get these type of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control how objects are serialized and deserialized by the C# MongoDB driver.
In this case, serializing the backing field for the property instread of the property itself should fix your problem. Check [this article](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial) in the MongoDB docs for more details on controlling serialization.

Using attributes, your source code would look something like this:

```
[BsonElement("Number")]
private int _number

[BsonIgnore]
public int Number  
{
  get { return _number; }
  set {
    _number = value

    //do not call this function during deserialization
    CallAnotherFunction()
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could setup a custom class map.

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyClass>(cm => {
   cm.AutoMap();
   cm.UnmapProperty(c => c.Number);
   cm.MapField("_number").SetElementName("Number");
});
```